# How to detect which column's value has updated in a Table

Tags: c#, sql-server

Suppose I have a student registration form with 85 fields in my c# project and there are three buttons Save, Update, Delete.
The person who update the field knows very well that which field has updated but how other person will know that which field has updated ? Because...
If I click update button without changing any value, the Update query execute and the same update query execute too when I click update button with some changes.
**So I want that database should detect which field has updated in update query.**
The traditional way says that store the previous values and then compare them with new values one by one field. But this slow down the performance. 
Any smart way ?

Comment: You could implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your classes and keep track that way

Comment: [SQL Server provides two features that track changes to data in a database: change data capture and change tracking.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: what kind of c# project? What data structures are you using? Change tracking is built into things like DataTables and ORMs.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement optimistic concurrent using a `rowversion` column. This avoids the need to check the old/new values of each column individually. Specify the original rowversion in the WHERE clause of the UPDATE statement and verify a row was updated. Proc example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.OptimisticConcurrencyExample(
    OptimisticConcurrencyExampleID int NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT PK_OptimisticConcurrencyExample PRIMARY KEY
    , Column1 int NOT NULL
    , Column2 int NOT NULL
    , Column3 int NOT NULL
    , RowVersion rowversion
);
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.UpdateOptimisticConcurrencyExample
      @OptimisticConcurrencyExampleID int
    , @Column1 int
    , @Column2 int
    , @Column3 int
    , @OriginalRowVersion rowversion
AS
UPDATE dbo.OptimisticConcurrencyExample
SET
      Column1 = @Column1
    , Column2 = @Column2
    , Column3 = @Column3
WHERE
    OptimisticConcurrencyExampleID = @OptimisticConcurrencyExampleID
    AND RowVersion = @OriginalRowVersion;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('data updated or deleted by another user', 16, 1);
END
GO
```

When an optimistic concurrency error occurs, the app code can refresh the data with the current values, let the user know someone else updated the row, and allow the user to re-enter changes. You could get fancy and transparently merge pending changes in code (checking old/new values for each column) and notifying the user only if a conflict occurs. Similarly, you could present the user with a merge form after a conflict with the entered and current values side-by-side and the different values marked, etc.

But given conflicts are typically rare (unlikely that different users will update the same student record at the same time), the additional development effort may not be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I have one way to do that thing using table versioning using that you can maintain every update, create, delete the record.

[Tutorial for table versioning](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40080.system-versioned-tables-in-sql-server-2016.aspx)

[Another Tutorial](http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/first-look-system-versioned-temporal-tables-part-1-creating-tables-and)

The second way is you have to add audit table or field that store SQL query and also store which user change the data and also store last modified date like that.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a save button and an update button? Same thing, right?

Modify the logic in your program to allow an update only if the user
   changes the data on the student registration form relative to the
   data in the database.

- Read record from database
- Store record data in a local `DataRow` or `List`
- Load data onto the student registration form
- `update_button.enable = false`
- `delete_button.enable = true`
- Create `TextChange` event methods for each `TextBox` on the student registration form
- When a `TextChange` event method fires, compare the `TextBox` text to the corresponding `DataRow` field or `List` item (case
  insensitive).
- If they don't match, enable the `update button`
- If the user clicks the `update button`, update the record and disable the `update button`